# Amazon Redshift how to copy from s3 and set a job_id

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Amazon Redshift provides the ability to load table data from s3 objects using the "Copy" command. Is their a way to use the copy command, but also set additional "col=CONSTANT" for each inserted row.

I want to set a job_id (which is not in the source data) on each copied row, and I think it would be a shame to have to execute a few million inserts just so each row has a job attribute, when "copy" gets me 99% of the way there with much better performance.

Maybe there is a more clever solution?

Answer (score 14):

If you want all your rows added in a single COPY command to have the same value of job_id, then you may COPY data into staging table, then add job_id column into that table, then insert all data from the staging table into final table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE destination_staging (LIKE destination);
ALTER TABLE destination_staging DROP COLUMN job_id;
COPY destination_staging FROM 's3://data/destination/(...)' (...)
ALTER TABLE destination_staging ADD COLUM job_id INT DEFAULT 42;
INSERT INTO destination SELECT * FROM destination_staging ORDER BY sortkey_column;
DROP TABLE destination_staging;
ANALYZE TABLE destination;
VACUUM destination;
```

ANALYZE and VACUUM are not necessary, but highly recommended in order to update query analyzer and put all new data into correct positions.

Comment: This would cause inconsistent behaviour if you tried to load more than one job at the same time, which is necessary. I suppose we could use "destination_staging_${jobId}" as the table, and that would keep things straight.

Comment: @gbegley, that is correct. You will have to create a separate staging table for each job_id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no option to do post/pre processing with the `COPY` command itself. Therefore your best option seems to be to do preprocessing to the files you intend to `COPY` into Redshift, add the jobid and then load them into Redshift.