# Redshift add column when importing with COPY

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift I have a table where I need to load data from multiple CSV files:

```
create table my_table (
  id integer,
  name varchar(50) NULL
  email varchar(50) NULL,
  processed_file varchar(256) NULL
);
```

The first three columns refer to data from the files. The last column `processed_filed` indicates from which file was the record imported.

I have the files in Amazon S3 and I want to import them with the `COPY` command. Something like:

```
COPY {table_name} FROM 's3://file-key' 
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxx' 
DATEFORMAT 'auto' TIMEFORMAT 'auto' MAXERROR 0 ACCEPTINVCHARS '*' DELIMITER '\t' GZIP;
```

Is there a way to populate the fourth `processed_file` column automatically with the COPY command, to insert the name of the file.

I can do an UPDATE statement after the COPY, but I am dealing with huge amounts of data, so ideally I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible.

You would need to either pre-process the files (to include a name column) or update the data after loading (but then it would be difficult to do a bulk-load from several files simultaneously, which is the most efficient way to load data into Redshift).

See: [Redshift `COPY` command documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try this custom logic for adding new column , in this example added file name as new column in redshift COPY

```
import boto3
import re
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

sql = "DROPSQL , CREATE SQL , COPY SQL" ## here need to pass your actual sqls

def Filter(datalist,keyword):
    # Search data based on regular expression in the list
    return [val for val in datalist
        if re.search(keyword, val)]

def add_new_col(table_name):
    drop_sql = ''.join(Filter(sql.split(';'),keyword=table_name+' '))
    create_sql = ''.join(Filter(sql.split(';'),keyword=table_name+'\('))
    copy_sql = ''.join(Filter(sql.split(';'),keyword=table_name.upper()+'/'))
    
    BUCKET = copy_sql.split(' ')[3].split('/')[2]
    folder = '/'.join(copy_sql.split(' ')[3].split('/')[3:-1])+'/'
    maintable = copy_sql.split(' ')[1]
    
    print ("BUCKET {}, key_folder {}, maintable {}".format(BUCKET,folder,maintable))
    
    temp_table_drop_sql = drop_sql.replace(table_name,'temp_table')
    temp_table_create_sql = create_sql.replace(table_name,'temp_table')
    temp_table_copy_sql = copy_sql.replace(table_name.upper(),'temp_table')
    temp_table_name_withSchema = temp_table_copy_sql.split(' ')[1]
    
    print ("temp_table_name_withSchema {}".format(temp_table_name_withSchema))
    
    ## replace with query execute logic
    print(temp_table_drop_sql)
    print(temp_table_create_sql)
    #####
    
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket=BUCKET,
            Prefix =folder)
    
    new_column_name = 'filename' 
    
    for i in response["Contents"]:
        ## replace with query execute logic
        temp_sql = copy_sql.replace(folder,i["Key"])
        temp_sql = temp_sql.replace(table_name.upper(),'temp_table')
        print(temp_sql)
        ## i["Key"] is filename
        print("alter table {} ADD COLUMN {} varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';".format(temp_table_name_withSchema, new_column_name , i["Key"].split('/')[-1]))
        print("insert into {} (select * from {})".format(maintable, temp_table_name_withSchema))
        print("truncate {}".format(temp_table_name_withSchema))
        #####
    
    ## replace with query execute logic
    print(drop_sql)
    ########
    
add_new_col(table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible. I am creating and loading the data without the extra `processed_file_name` column and afterwards adding the column with a default value. Here is the full process:

```
create table my_table (
  id integer,
  name varchar(50) NULL
  email varchar(50) NULL,
);

COPY {table_name} FROM 's3://file-key' 
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxx' 
DATEFORMAT 'auto' TIMEFORMAT 'auto' MAXERROR 0 ACCEPTINVCHARS '*' DELIMITER '\t' GZIP;

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN processed_file_name varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{file-name}';
```

This works for my use case, as I am doing this on staging tables, that will hold data from only one file, before they are truncated and the data is transferred to the target tables.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that you proposed.  You're putting an static value into the column that you are defaulting.  Every file you load ends up with the same value. Try this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525175/amazon-redshift-how-to-copy-from-s3-and-set-a-job-id

Comment: This was ok for my use case, as the table I was using was a staging_table, that would truncated after the data is transferred to the target table