# Incorporate File Name in Redshift COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to load ~2 million CSV files from an S3 bucket to a Redshift table. This would be easy (just use a `COPY` with a wildcard or a manifest file), except that I need to incorporate the name of each file into the resulting table. Suppose `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` both contain:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

I want my table to have

```
file1 a b c
file1 d e f
file2 a b c
file2 d e f
```

Is there a way this can be accomplished with a single `COPY` statement? Or will I need to iterate through the list of files and load/insert them one at a time?

I suspect the latter option would be a massive performance hit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

Here is a brief thread on the AWS forum, with a response from AWS that the have "created a feature request" but "cannot provide an ETA on this":
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=590722&#590722

A similar question already on Stack Exchange:
[Redshift add column when importing with COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336070/redshift-add-column-when-importing-with-copy)